# Can't get my background image to morph correctly based on screen size expansion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to have a simple square background image with a navbar. I've been able to get the image and navbar up and going, but the image itself is not expanding how I want. On a phone I want it fitted from top to bottom but the sides run off, then as the screen gets bigger it slowly moves into it's full shape, then final at its desktop size it's centered with a black background filling out what the image can't cover without obviously being stretched. Would greatly appreciate help, example below.

[WHAT I WANT](https://imgur.com/a/dBdKwgP)

[WHAT'S HAPPENING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uT1C.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Put your image on the div so it can be easily to adjust.

```
div {
    background: url('putyoururlhere');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30vh;
}
```

Put a width and height to it according to what do you want.

Comment: So this has help me immensely. Looks great on a phone but when it expands for desktop I need it to be a perfect square within the screen. Meaning the background color would then be shown on the sides of the perfect square image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
div {
    background-image: url('putyoururlhere');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30vh;
}
```